# How to make a host file available inside a container using Maven Jib plugin

Tags: maven, docker-volume, jib

I am building a container using Jib's Maven plugin.

I have a file called `/tmp/folder/file.json` on my host machine, which I need to be able to read from inside a container.

I tried to mount `/tmp/folder` using the volumes feature:

```
  <plugin>
     <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
     <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0</version>
     <configuration>
       <to>
          <image>myimage</image>
       </to>
       <container>
           <volumes>
               <volume>/tmp/folder</volume>
           </volumes>
       </container>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

I think `/tmp/folder` is accessible from the container but `file.json` isn't. At least when I try this

```
 docker exec -it my_cotainer /bin/ls /tmp/folder
```

Nothing comes back.

Am I using the volumes feature correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify `from` property the default `gcr.io/distroless/java` image is used. You can execute `/bin/ls` using this image.

> "Distroless" images contain only your application and its runtime dependencies. They do not contain package managers, shells or any other programs you would expect to find in a standard Linux distribution.

Try to build from linux based image.

```
  <plugin>
     <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
     <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0</version>
     <configuration>
       <from>
          <image>openjdk:8-jre-alpine</image>
       </from>
       <to>
          <image>myimage</image>
       </to>
       <container>
           <volumes>
               <volume>/tmp/folder</volume>
           </volumes>
       </container>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
```